# NPM Concurrently not running mocha test

Tags: npm, mocha.js

I am using the npm package [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) to run multiple processes needed for a test.

When I run mocha alone like this:

```
./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha  --harmony ./tests/
```

it works fine.  But when I try to use it with **concurrently** like this:

```
./node_modules/concurrently/src/main.js "./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha  --harmony ./tests/"
```

I get an error like this:

```
throw new Error("must provide pattern")
[0]           ^
[0] Error: must provide pattern
[0]     at new Glob (/Users/my-project/node_modules/mocha/node_modules/glob/glob.js:121:11)
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked by adding the mocha part as a script in package.json

`"scripts": {
    "mocha": "./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha  --harmony ./tests/"
  },`

and then this:

`./node_modules/concurrently/src/main.js "npm run mocha"`